# xlsxWriter issue regarding exporting dates as dates

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a list that includes dates in the following format: 11/22/2019.
When I export this list to Excel, The Excel sheet recognizes these dates as General and therefor I cannot sort on these dates. Is there a way to make these dates recognizable by Excel as dates without using VBA?

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 1")

dates_array = ["02/12/1999", "04/12/2009", "11/02/2019"]
# Export dates_array to Excel file
row = 0
column = 0
for item in dates_array:
    worksheet.write(row, column, item)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking those aren’t dates, they are just strings that look like dates. You need to convert them into dates, which in Python is generally a datetime object and in Excel is a real number + a format.

XlsxWriter can convert Python datetime objects into Excel dates but it doesn’t automagically convert date-like strings to Excel dates. This is explained in more detail in the [Working with Dates and Times](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Here is an example of how you could convert them:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 1")

dates_array = ["02/12/1999", "04/12/2009", "11/02/2019"]
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})

# Set the column width for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 20)

row = 0
column = 0
for item in dates_array:

    date_time = datetime.strptime(item, '%m/%d/%Y')

    worksheet.write(row, column, date_time, date_format)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Cell formatting, like the above, overrides column formatting so if you want to set a column format then you can omit the cell format, like this:

```py
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 20, date_format)

row = 0
column = 0
for item in dates_array:

    date_time = datetime.strptime(item, '%m/%d/%Y')

    worksheet.write(row, column, date_time)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Finally, if you want to also add vertical alignment to the column format you can add that to the date format, like this:

```py
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy', 
                                   'align': 'vcenter'})
```

Comment: Correct. I was aware that they are just strings that look like dates. However, I am getting these strings from an outside source as is. This is why roadrunner66 solution solved my problem except the overriding issue that I mentioned in my previous comment.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comments and the question about overriding the column format.

Comment: Thanks. it works correctly now. The only thing that is odd is that when I look at he resulting worksheet, I noticed that the dates values can be sorted correctly, however the values of the dates are displayed as Custom. When I select the dates values and I select short date, the values are displayed as dates. As long as I can sort correctly on the dates' values, this issue is not a show stopper for me however it does bother me.

Comment: The Date/Custom difference depends on whether the number format matches one of the default date formats on your system. For example, when I run the above sample code it shows up in Excel as a Date format. This is explained in a bit more detail in the docs: [XlsxWriter - The Format Class - Number Format Categories](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-format-categories)

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me, but I can't explain why Excel does recognize certain date formats when entered manually, but leaves those formats as text when entered with xlsxwriter.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 1")

dates_array = [" 02/30/1999", "04/12/2009", "11/02/2019"]
# Export dates_array to Excel file
row = 0
column = 0
for item in dates_array:
    worksheet.write(row, column, item)
    format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'm/d/yyyy'})
    worksheet.write(row,column, item, format)      
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: It works now great. Thanks a lot. I think that Excel leaves those formats as text when entered with xlsxWriter because for whatever reason Excel interprets this text as CSV format. Therefore when you go to the spreadsheet and select Data -> Text to Column -> Finish, all the text in the column will change to dates. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: There is a problem. I forgot to mention that in my real application, I had the following format statement: cell_format.set_align('vcenter')  followed by worksheet.write(row, column, item). Therefor your formatting statement overrides the vertical align format. How can I have both formats working?